# Many stack allocations vs. dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, heap-memory, stack-memory

In a multi-dimensional array where the second dimension will be of known sizes (albeit different per each first dimension), would it be faster *performance-wise* for the actual building of these arrays to hardcode:

```
int* number[1000];

int secondDim[1];
number[0] = secondDim;

int secondDimTwo[2];
number[1] = secondDim;
```

etc. etc. 1,000 times (I know, I know)

or dynamically allocate each second dimension:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    number[i] = new int[i+1];
```

Just trying to wrap my head around a concept here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule you can assume, that stack allocations will be faster. Just remember that stack has limited capacity, and overuse of large stack-allocated arrays might lead to, wait for it... stack overflow!

Anyways, your question is valid, but the solutions I've seen so far are extremely limited. The thing is, you can easily create utility type, that will act as triangular matrix, and then it's up to specific use case whether you'll store it on the stack or heap. Observe:

```
namespace meta
{
    template <size_t N>
    struct sum
    {
        static const int value = (N + 1) * N / 2;
    };
}

template <size_t Size>
struct MultiArray
{
    // actual buffer
    int numbers[ meta::sum<Size>::value ];

    // run-time indexing
    int* getArray(size_t dimensions)
    {
        // get sum of (dimensions-1)
        size_t index = (dimensions * (dimensions-1)) >> 1;
        return &numbers[index];
    }

    // compile-time indexing
    template <size_t dimensions>
    int* getArray()
    {
        size_t index = meta::sum<dimensions - 1>::value ;
        return &numbers[ index ];
    }

    int* operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return getArray(index);
    }
};
```

Now it's up to you where to store it.

```
MultiArray<1000> storedOnStack;
MultiArray<1000>* storedOnHeap = new MultiArray<1000>();
```

You have to accessors to get to the inner arrays:

```
int* runTimeResolvedArray = storedOnStack.getArray(10);
int* compileTimeResolvedArray = storedOnStack.getArray<10>();
int* runTimeResolvedArray2 = storedOnStack[10];
storedOnStack[10][0] = 666;
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: 
I also must say that I don't like the term "stack allocation". It's misleading. Stack allocation is essentially just an increase in stack pointer register. So, if you "allocate" 100 bytes on stack the pointer will be increased by 100 bytes. But if you allocate 100 bytes on heap, then it gets complicated - current allocator has to find suitable empty memory space, update alloc map and so on, so on.

If it's one time allocation - go ahead and do it on the heap, the overhead of dynamic allocation won't be noticable. But if do it many times per second, then opt for stack allocation. Also, stack arrays can be potentially faster to access, because stack contents are more likely to be in cache. But obviously really huge arrays won't fit cache. So, the anwser is: *profile*.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the size of the array you need, You should use a array on the stack.
Note that Usually, dynamic allocations are costlier than allocations on stack.
If the difference in performance is significant enough for your case can only be determined by profiling.

Also, avoid dynamic allocations because they are more error prone unless you use some sort of resource management based on **[RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)**.

Comment: Is there a faster way to actually code that than hard-coding as I did above?

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to allocate the entire array in one go so all the data is contiguous(better caching).

int * arr;
arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*sum(1,n)); you must define the sum function.

Simply allocate a 2d array(first dim) and set the pointers to the correct location in arr.

Comment: No.  You don't want to use `malloc` (nor `new[]`), ever.  The only time dynamic allocation in application code is appropriate is for single elements; as soon as more than one element is present, use `std::vector`.

Comment: Is this as fast to allocate for large arrays as using the stack? Accessing speed as fast as well? Speed is the only priority in my circumstance

Answer (score 1):

Until you have actually profiled, and know that the dynamic allocation
is an issue:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > number;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++ i ) {
    number.push_back( std::vector<int>( i + 1 );
}
```

or (probably slightly faster, especially if your compiler doesn't have
move semantics yet):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > number( 1000 );
for ( size_t i = 0; i != number.size() ; ++ i ) {
    number[i].resize( i + 1 );
}
```

If this does cause performance problems, or perhaps just to better
encapsulate, you can write a simple class which represents the data
structure:

```
class TriangularMatrix
{
    std::vector<int> myData;
    size_t mySize;

    size_t rowIndex( size_t i ) const
    {
        return (i * (i + 1)) / 2;
    }
public:
    TriangularMatrix( size_t size )
        : myData( rowIndex( size ) )
        , mySize( size )
    {
    }
    int* operator[]( size_t i )  // Returns row
    {
        assert( i < mySize );
        return &myData[rowIndex( i )];
    }
    int const* operator[]( size_t i ) const  // Returns row
    {
        assert( i < mySize );
        return &myData[rowIndex( i )];
    }
    int& operator( int i, int j )  // indexation
    {
        assert( j <= i );
        return operator[]( i )[ j ];
    }
    int const& operator( int i, int j ) const  // indexation
    {
        assert( j <= i );
        return operator[]( i )[ j ];
    }
};
```

In fact, I think something like this would be much cleaner and more
readable.

Comment: It would be cleaner to define a `Row` class as a slice of `myData` instead of returning a raw `int*`. Not only would it make the comment redundant, but it would also ensure proper bound checking.

Comment: Appending/accessing items to/from a vector is faster than allocating/accessing to/from the stack? For the sake of the argument, assuming the speed is needed.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Agreed.  But the code sample already seemed a bit long.

Comment: @user1201584 Access should be about the same; it depends a lot on the compiler optimizer.  At any rate, the index calculation is likely to predominate.  (Depending on the machine, it may be worth creating a cache for the index.  Although on most modern machines, I suspect that `(i + (i + 1)) / 2` is faster than a memory access.)  And the (single) vector is dimensioned with the correct size from the beginning. With encapsulation, it's almost impossible to avoid the single dynamic allocation, and without the encapsulation, something like this is almost impossible to maintain.